# How can I pass dynamic values to elasticsearch query from python

Tags: python, variables, elasticsearch

I am trying to retrieve data from elastic search using python script and I need the data only for specific values.

```
POST _search 
{
 "sort": [
    {
       "dimensions.memberId.string_value": {
          "order": "desc"
       }
    }
 ],
 "from": 0,
 "size": 20,
 "fields": [
    "dimensions.memberId.string_value",
    "measures.ce_timeStamp"
 ], 
 "query": {
    "bool": {
       "must": [
          {
             "term": {
                "eventType": "GG"
             }
          },
          {
             "term": {
                "corporateId": "abc"
             }
          },
          {
             "terms": {
                 "memberId.string_value": ["127281961", "127274705"]
             }
          },
          {
             "terms": {
                 "status.string_value": ["B", "P", "C", "A"]
             }
          }
       ]
    }
 }
}
```

This is my actual query and I want to send the memberIds as a variable in python.

I have constructed the whole query as a variable as below:

```
queryPart1 = " {\"sort\": [ \
      { \
         \"dimensions.memberId.string_value\": { \
            \"order\": \"desc\" \
         } \
      }\
   ],\
   \"from\": 0, \
   \"size\": 20, \
   \"fields\": [ \
      \"dimensions.memberId.string_value\", \
      \"measures.ce_timeStamp\" \
   ],  \
   \"query\": { \
      \"bool\": { \
         \"must\": [ \
            { \
               \"term\": { \
                  \"eventType\": \"GG\" \
               } \
            }, \
            { \
               \"term\": { \
                  \"corporateId\": \"ABC\" \
               } \
            }, \
            { \
               \"terms\": { \
                   \"dimensions.memberId.string_value\": "

  queryPart2 = "} \
            }, \
            { \
               \"terms\": { \
                   \"dimensions.1_shipment_status.string_value\": [\"B\", \"P\", \"C\", \"A\"] \
               } \
            } \
          ] \
        } \
      } \
    }"



querybody = queryPart1+varMemberId+queryPart2
```

and varMemberID is the variable with concatenated values

This is not working for me. Can you please point out what is wrong with this method?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import json

l = ["value1", "value2"]

\"dimensions.memberId.string_value\": + json.dumps(list) + queryPart2
```

However, I suggest looking at [elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) client. It will make your code much simpler and easier to debug.

Comment: `list` is a preserved word in Python. Please don't use it as a variable

Answer (score 0):

The request you are making is in the form of JSON string. Python provides [`json`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module to efficiently handle JSON data. You can use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) to convert the dict/list object to JSON string.

For example:

```
import json

my_variable = 33   # variable you want to pass

params = {
   'param1': 'value_1',
   'param2': 'value_2',
   'param3': my_variable   # your variable
}

json_str = json.dumps(params)
# `json_str` will hold the value in the form of json string as:
# '{"param3": 33, "param2": "value_2", "param1": "value_1"}' 
#              ^  value of your variable
```